# How to resize image in mdpi, ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi

Tags: android, photoshop

I have simple png logo. I want to resize it in 24*24 mdpi,72*72 hdpi for android. can I do it with photoshop..? or please suggest the way to do it.

Comment: I do it with Adobe XD. It's free and You can export selcted png's in all sizes You need for android multi monitor layout

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I wrote a Photoshop's plugin to create different copies of a source image.

You can get it and its source from GitHub, [ic_launcher_exporter](https://github.com/xcesco/ic_launcher_exporter). If you like it, please remember to give it a star :). I hope this helps.

[image: ic_launcher_exporter]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about photoshop but maybe this tool can help you: [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_ac_unit)

Answer (score 0):

Just search for "android app icon generator" or similar. You will find lots of websites allowing you to do it online.